# Use a Drop Down Menu to Query A Database and Return the Results Either On The Same Page Or Another Page

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a page with some PHP that looks like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="wheniwant">Date</th>
            <th class="wheniwant">Income Amount</th>
            <th class="wheniwant">Expense Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php
    //DB CONNECTION

    $varDatePaid = ""; $varIncomePaid =""; $varExpensePaid = "";

    $sql = mysql_query( 
        "
            SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date_paid`, '%Y-%m') `date_paid`,
            SUM(CASE WHEN `categoryType` = 'Income' THEN `amount_paid` END) `IncomeAmount`,
            SUM(CASE WHEN `categoryType` = 'Expense' THEN `amount_paid` END) `ExpenseAmount`
            FROM `accounting`
            GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date_paid`, '%Y-%m')
        "
     );


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $varDatePaid = $row['date_paid'];
            $varIncomePaid = $row['IncomeAmount'];
            $varExpensePaid = $row['ExpenseAmount'];                        
    ?>


    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $varDatePaid; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $varIncomePaid; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $varExpensePaid; ?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php   

        }
    ?>
</table>
```

This returns a table like:

[image: Screenshot]

I want to then add something:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(`date_paid`, '%Y') AS year FROM accounting GROUP BY year ORDER BY year DESC";


$result = mysql_query($sql_query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<option value='. $row['year'] . '>'. $row['year'] . '</option>';
```

To create some sort of filter to limit the result to a particular year. How do I do this without leaving the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first define the dropdown in the html and submit it when the selected value changes:

```
<form id="myForm" action="samePage.php" method="post">
<select id="mySelection" name="mySelection" onChange="$('#myForm').submit();">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</form>
```

and you modify the query in the php to filter by the selected value:

```
$sql = mysql_query(  
                      "
                      SELECT *
                      FROM TableName
                      where ColumnName like '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mySelection']) . "%'
              ORDER BY something ASC
                      "
                     );
```

I didn't test the code, but you should get the idea from here. And i assumed you use jquery for the *$('#myForm').submit()* script.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really provided enough info or anything that you've tried.

You're going to need a HTML form, with the `<select>` boxes on it that have a unique ID so you can grab the values in PHP via $_POST and then input these in to the SQL in a "WHERE" statement.

E.g.

```
<form action="script.php" method="post">
    <select id="filter">
        <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
        <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Filter">
</form>
```

In script.php:

```
<?php
 // DB connect
 $filter = $_POST['filter'];
 $query = "
                  SELECT *
                  FROM TableName
          WHERE field_to_filter = '$filter'
          ORDER BY something ASC
                  "
 //etc
 ?>
```

Note, this is a very brief example off the top of my head. It will vary hugely based on what exactly you're trying to do. Plus this doesn't take in to account any security issues with accepting user input from forms and passing it to SQL.

If script.php is the current page, pressing the submit button will simply refresh the page with the filter now in place. Some more code will be needed for things such as making sure the select box has the previous selection still active. If you don't want to refresh the page, then something like jQuery will be required which will add another level of complexity if you haven't use it before.